# Is it possible to stab every permutation of any four element subset of $D_n$ with less than $n/2$ elements?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, polymath16

Say for a permutation group $G$ over $n$ that a set $S\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is *G-stabbed* by $X\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$ if for every $g\in G$ we have $gS\cap X\ne \emptyset$.

> Is there for every $|S|=4$ an $|X|<n/2$ that $D_n$-stabs it?

My motivation comes from [here](https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2019/07/08/polymath16-thirteenth-thread-bumping-the-deadline/#comment-23883), where we would could improve the number of added edges.
I checked by hand, and it seems that there are no counterexamples for $n \le 8$.
The problem was solved for $\mathbb Z_n$ instead of $D_n$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337047).

Comment: The greedy algorithm approach I used for the other problem only manages $0.565 n$ for this one.  However for $|S|=5$ it gives $0.498n$.